# CheerioJS - Return True if two items present within a div

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to write a script with Node and Cheerio JS that checks a website and returns true if tickets are available for a certain teams game. The basic HTML structure of the site is

```
<body>
    <div class="competition">
      <div class="match">
        <div class="team-info">
          <h3>
            <span class="team">Team 1</span>
            <span class="team">Team 2</span>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="buy-info">
          <div class="btn available">Buy</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="match">
        <div class="team-info">
          <h3>
            <span class="team">Team 3</span>
            <span class="team">Team 4</span>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="buy-info">
          <div class="btn available">Buy</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I want to use Cheerio and with an each() function, check each **match** class and return true of 'Team 1' is the text value of the **team** span and the corresponding Buy button has the class **available**. I have written the below so far but on my real life example, it is returning the number of total **available** buttons * the amount of games 'Team 1' play.

```
const teamFinder = ".team";
// set match day class
    const match = ".match";
    let MatchCount = 0;

    $(match).each((MDIdx, MDElm) => {
      $(teamFinder).each((parentIdx, parentElm) => {
        let team = $(parentElm).text();

        if (team == "Team 1") {
          if ($(buttonDiv).children().hasClass("available")) {
            MatchCount++;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Are you returning true if all `.match .available`s in the whole document have team 1, or making an array of the true/false results for each match, or producing a count of the matches that meet the conditions? I'm not sure I understand the expected output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that your inner each() iterates over all elements found in html, and not current .match div.
so, instead of:
`$(teamFinder).each()`

you should use:
`$(teamFinder, MDElm).each()`

Here is the fixed example:
https://scrapeninja.net/cheerio-sandbox?slug=b9db2202ea00e21f7d7197b1667802edd411ea33

## a "cleaner" approach:

```js
// define function which accepts body and cheerio as args
function extract(input, cheerio) {
    // return object with extracted values              
    let $ = cheerio.load(input);

    // extract all matches
    let matches = $('.match').map((k, v) => {
        return {
            teams: $('.team', v).map((k, v) => $(v).text().trim()).toArray(),
            available: $('.buy-info .available', v).length
        }
    }).toArray();

    // pure JSON with matches
    console.log(matches);

    let matchCount = matches.filter(m => m.teams.includes('Team 1') && m.available).length;
    console.log(`matchCount: ${matchCount}`);
}
```

https://scrapeninja.net/cheerio-sandbox?slug=2b6fd73137469289934c42294bba18fa1cbfa355

Comment: Thanks a million Anthony. I thought the same about the issue but didn't know the solution! Appreciate the quick response